# NEC Infra-red remote control protocol address registry

Tags: protocols, infrared

AFAICT the NEC IR protocol works by sending a "Device Address" which can be either 8 bits followed by the inverse of the initial 8 bits, or 16 bits where the second 8 bits don't match the inverse of the first 8 bits.

I want to create my own two button IR control to switch two amplifiers to a set of speakers (only one amp can connect).

Clearly I don't want to conflict with devices I already own, so is there a registry of the assigned device addresses?  Or do I need to just try one and see if it conflicts with devices I already have (that doesn't sound a great approach).

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

There is a program in android which name is "IrCode Finder". If you have a Infrared in your phone, you can find your device's address with Autotest. This program tests your device for all address if your device gives response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).